# Which technology to use for buildng touch screen apps for big screen(40'') in .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, wpf, html, winforms

I need to create an application in .net which will run on a big touch screen 40'' .Now my question is which technology i should use for building this application.
The application will be reporting/drag and drop functionality(will be used to assign groups tasks to user). Which of the following tehnology i should use
1. WPF
2. MVC, html , jquery
3. Windows forms

Any response will be appreciated.
Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: If it is a Desktop app, go with WPF. If it is web app, go with MVC (using HTMl and jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success building touch based applications in WPF for large touch screens.

It depends on the other hardware, if you're running it in on a PI, this isn't going to help!

If you've got a windows host machine, go WPF. It runs natively, easy to scale to differing screen resolutions and supports diverse manipulations such as pinch and rotate.